# Check BUTTON type = submit is clicked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to check if button type submit is clicked, I have two buttons in the same form.

View sample

```
{!!Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'type' => 'submit', 'name'=> 'movetrash'))!!}
```

I am not able to check with below

`Input::get('movetrash')`.

This is how my condition looks like

```
if(Input::get('movetrash')) {
    //do something is movetrash is clicked. 
} else {
    //perform other task
}
```

When I submit the form with `Form::submit()` method then it works great:

```
{!!Form::submit('Move to Trash', 
 array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name'=> 'movetrash'))!!}
```

but not with the below method (`Form::button()`). And I am unable to make it work with method shown below. All thought it also post the form data.

```
{!!Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>', 
 array('class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'type' => 'submit', 'name'=> 'movetrash'))!!}
```

Comment: You have to send it through form (either POST or GET).

Comment: Yes i created a form already its sending value from `{!!Form::submit('Move to Trash', array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name'=> 'movetrash'))!!}` but not with `{!!Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'type' => 'submit', 'name'=> 'movetrash'))!!}`

Comment: Nice, so go and edit the question with all that code. Also specify what version of laravel you use.

Comment: Have you checked console? How that 2nd button looks like? From your code it looks good.

Comment: Yes in terms of code it looks good. But i guess there is no way to do `Button::get('movetrash')` i have searched all over internet